# Abruptly the LaTex content is lost?

Tags: errors, compiling

I have been creating a document on LaTex, TexStudio. Recently, I had pressed the Compile+Run button on it. The computer was hanged and I had to restart it. Now, the content of the document is lost and the pdf generated by it is also corrupted and does not open.

What could be the issue. How, can I recover it !

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: Try to look for temporary files!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329665/the-latex-file-coding-is-not-there-but-the-pdf-file-is-there/329708#329708

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX-SX.

First of all, I would suggest you to save your files before compiling, at least the first time. If you do not save the file intentionally, TeXstudio will compile it as a *temp*orary file, as you can check at the imagem. The name will be "texstudio_something".

[image]

These files are stored at the `AppData\Local\Temp`.
[image]

Which you can access through any folder by typing `%appdata%` at the path bar.

If you have saved your file, then you may just compile it without any worries like the one you had, because TeXstudio will then save it on the previous file.

I'm assuming your problem is not that a already saved file has been overwritten after a compilation. After all crashes and erros I have had, I do not remember any loss of data in a saved file.

You can find some more advice at [TexStudio Autosave Recovery Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/texstudio-autosave-recovery-question).

Comment: Quick note: You can find the folder `Temp` directly with the shortcut `%temp%`.